# How to use a set comprehension for the body of a function

Tags: alloy

Suppose I have the following signatures:

```
sig A {}
sig B {}

sig P {
    a: A,
    b: B
}
```

How can I write a function `f`, say, such that `f` returns the set of `P` for which each member has the value `x: A` for its `a` field?

Entering the expression `{p: P | p.a = x}` into the evaluator gives me back a set, but when I try to define `f` in this manner

```
fun f(a: A) : set P {
    { p: P | p.a = a }
}
```

alloy tells me I've made an error:

> A type error has occurred
>   This cannot be a legal relational join where
>   left hand side is p (type = {this/P})
>   right hand side is a (type = {this/A})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you shadowed the `a` relation with your function parameter. It works if you replace `f(a: A)` with `f(a': A)`. Alternatively, you can use the `@` operator, which returns the global instead of local value of a set:

```
fun f(a: A) : set P {
    { p: P | p.@a = a }
}
```

Comment: That caught me out before.  Thanks!